# how to open link in terminal app in macos?

Tags: terminal

For instance if I have link with special protocol `foobar://` I want to open such link in terminal.

Flow:

- open browser
- find link like `foobar://bazeggsspam`
- click the link
- browser redirects to the terminal and run command `mycmd -l {link}`

(I know that this looks like security vulnerability, but still wonder if such feature exists)

Or do I need to make `.app` which should receive permissions from OS to open custom links?

Answer (score 0):

I’m quite sure that this is the one you are looking for.

> [LinCastor](https://onflapp.wordpress.com/lincastor/) enables you to register your own custom URL protocol scheme (e.g. mylink://foo/bar) and associate it with an application, shell or AppleScript handler.

As most OS X application support embedding links as part of a text, a custom URL protocol scheme provides a great way to connect different applications together or trigger custom workflows. For example: a link jira://issue1234 could open a JIRA tracker with specific issue. This link could then be placed in iCal’s reminder or any other text fields supporting links.